# Problem with Google Analytics module: "undefined index"

Tags: google-analytics

I use "Google Analytics" module (version 7.x-2.1 = up to date) and I get the following error message:

> Notice : Undefined index: value in googleanalytics_page_alter() (ligne
>   217 in
>   .../www/sites/all/modules/google_analytics/googleanalytics.module)

Any idea how can I solve it? Perhaps some manual modifications in the googleanalytics.module file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined index message in drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14782/undefined-index-message-in-drupal)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan: Technically it is on topic because it is a module support request, not a bug or feature request. Even though it looks like a bug report until you look into it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a support request on Drupal.org for this [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2392371).

Since it is not really a bug or feature request though it is technically on topic here so the summary of that issue is:

1. Make sure that you have [run update.php](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/running-update-php#run-update-php).
2. If that didn't fix the problem then try re-saving your google analytics settings (it would be a good idea to confirm that they are what they should be before saving).

Also I would recommend that if you get error messages like that to search google and the drupal.org issue queue for the module(s) in question.

Comment: Your advice (n°2) worked. Thanks! By the way, I searched before posting here... (I know the "policy" on SE sites) but without success.

Comment: Search tip for drupal module bugs is to search in google like this: drupal MODULE_NAME ERROR_MESSAGE. But only the actual error message, not the file name or line number. If you end up needing to include the file name then omit the path and just use the file name. When I did that in this case the drupal.org issue I linked to was the first result.